# Reference for the polar parameterization of quaternions

Tags: specific-reference, rotation

I would like to find the original reference in which the polar parameterization of quaternions was given (i.e. the relationship between the components of a unit quaternion and the polar angles of an axis and rotation angle of a three-dimensional rotation). I assume it would have been written by Hamilton, but the physics literature from the 60's doesn't really point back any further (See, e.g. Biedenharn LC. J Math Phys 1961;2:433, equation 10). Any suggestions?

Comment: Kudos on proper use of the [tag:reference-request] tag ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [paper](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Quatern1/Quatern1.pdf) you are looking for.

All the [mathematical papers](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Papers.html) of Hamilton.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of first link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.